# Calculating f_score[neighbor] for A* search

Tags: java, algorithm, search

I'm looking at the A star psuedo code on wikipedia ([wikipedia:A*_search_algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A%2a_search_algorithm)) and I have a question on this snippet of code:

```
for each neighbor in neighbor_nodes(current)
    tentative_g_score := g_score[current] + dist_between(current,neighbor)
    tentative_f_score := tentative_g_score + heuristic_cost_estimate(neighbor, goal)
    if neighbor in closedset and tentative_f_score >= f_score[neighbor]
        continue
```

In the second part of the if statement - `tentative_f_score >= f_score[neighbor]` - I'm wondering how calculating `f_score[neighbor]` would be different from calculating `tentative_f_score`.

Basically, how would I calculate `f_score[neighbor]`? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`f_score[neighbor]` is something you store for all nodes. This neighbor is a node that you already have an F-score for, because it is already in the closed set. The new F-score can be different, because you didn't reach that node in the same way that you've reached it before, so the parent would be different than what you've already stored for that node (and therefore potentially also the G, and therefore F).

Basically the condition there says what happens if that *isn't* the case (or if the new F is worse), then you can just ignore that node.

The code right below it deals with the case where the new path found to that node is shorter than how you reached it before, so it sets the current node as its parent and updates its G (and therefore F).

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I did some research and found out that f(v) = g(v) + h(v), where v is some vertex in a graph. so should f(neighbor) = g(neighbor) + h(neighbor) where g(neighbor) = tentative_g_score + cost from going from node "neighbor" to its successor?

Comment: @user1923 The tentative scores are the scores associated with "trying a new path to that node", the G of the neighbor may *become* the tentative G if it is found to be better than the old G of that neighbor (note by the way that the cost of moving to it is already included, that's what the `+ dist_between(current,neighbor)` does).

Comment: Just to clarify, are you stating that my above formula is correct? I see g[neighbors] as defined to be the cost from the start node all the way to the "neighbor" node + distance of edge from "neighbor" node to successor + heuristic of "neighbor" node to goal.

Comment: @user1923 G is just the cost from the start to the node. H is the expected cost from the node to the goal. F is defined by `f(v) = g(v) + h(v)`. The G of the neighbor is the cost of the best previously-found path to that neighbor, which is in this code being compared with a new way to reach that node (namely, first to the current node, and then immediately to that neighbor). If you're asking about `g(neighbor) = tentative_g_score + something`, that one doesn't really make sense.

Comment: Oh okay, I get it. Thanks for your help!